# Can Julia warnings during 'using' be selectively disabled?

Tags: julia

Julia v0.6.2 
BloomFilters had been installed earlier.

```
julia> using BloomFilters
WARNING: Array(::Type{T}, m::Int) where T is deprecated, use Array{T}(m) instead.
Stacktrace:
 [1] depwarn(::String, ::Symbol) at ./deprecated.jl:70
 [2] Array(::Type{Any}, ::Int64) at ./deprecated.jl:57
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:576
 ....  
 [14] (::Base.REPL.##1#2{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:73
 while loading /Users//.julia/v0.6/BloomFilters/src/probabilities.jl,  in expression starting on line 5
```

It seems to works fine otherwise, and at some point the maintainers for BloomFilters will likely deal with the deprecation. In the meantime, is it possible to selectively turn off warnings for a specific package?  I would not want to turn off warnings (even identical ones to this one) for other packages, i.e. globally.

Comment: Note that the logging in Julia v0.7/v1.0 was overhauled in a way that this can be added as a standard part of the language, though this specific feature wasn't added yet but is planned in a 1.x.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas is v0.7 available and stable?

Comment: Not yet. v0.7 is the developer's version of Julia v1.0. The feature freeze should come any week, and then there will be a long beta phase to get rid of the bugs. So essentially, v1.0 should come in a few months and tags where each warning comes from, so at least if it isn't implemented then you can throw together your own in a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/Ismael-VC/Suppressor.jl)

```
using Suppressor: @suppress_err

@suppress_err using BloomFilters
```

Comment: Suppressor works nicely.  have tested it both in REPL and IJulia notebook

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this in a command line REPL, you can start Julia with the `--depwarn=no` flag, which will remove all deprecation warnings.

If you wish to do this with IJulia, for example in a notebook, you will need to add this flag to the Julia kernel initialization script. There should be a `kernel.json` file that will have to be updated.

Alternatively, you can redirect all `stdout` and `stderr` temporarily to "disable" warnings interactively.

Edit: I should read the question more carefully. This will disable all warnings for all packages. Check out Suppressor.jl.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  However  the question as stated is to **Selectively** turn off warnings only for **specific packages**.

Comment: You are right, I'll edit my answer. Redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` is an option for that, which is what I believe Suppressor.jl does.